# Web Api загрузить файл из формы и получить другой обратно

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net, webapi

Мне необходимо получить файл в Api контроллер, обработать его и отослать его обратно. Поэтому мне необходим submit формы, а не Ajax запрос. Как я могу считать файл в контроллере?
HTML:

```
    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="api/HeatConfig/GenerateDxf">
        <input name="file" type="file" />
        <input type="submit" value="Генерация" />
    </form>
```

Метод контроллера:

```
    [HttpGet]
    public HttpResponseMessage GenerateDxf()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage result = null;

        var httpRequest = HttpContext.Current.Request;

        if (httpRequest.Files.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (string file in httpRequest.Files)
            {
                var postedFile = httpRequest.Files[file];
            }

        }

        var uploadedFile = httpRequest.Params["file"];

        return CreateFileResult(new byte[666], "DxfDocumentation.dxf");

    }
```

Не получается никак считать файл - отладчик показывает, что он пустой. Точнее, что нет ни одного файла.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй воспользоваться этим способом

```
var file = Request.Form.Files[0];
```